# How can I use two conditions in duplicate function?

Tags: r

I've got a data.frame with this data and 10 columns

```
ID  | sequence | modification| ... | nºproject
DAT | atggggg  | NULL        | ... | project 
DAT | atggggg  | 7.UN        | ... | project 
DAT | actgat   | NULL        | ... | project 
DAT | atgtagtt | NULL        | ... | project 
DAT | ttttaaat | 8.UN        | ... | project 
DAT | tatatccc | NULL        | ... | project 
DAT | atagattg | 9.AT        | ... | project 
DAT | atatagag | NULL        | ... | project 
DAT | gggatgac | NULL        | ... | project
```

I've been using this codes to find duplicates.

```
data_table <- data.table(new_data_frame_PEP$sequence, new_data_frame_PEP$modifications)
colnames(data_table) <- c("sequence","modifications")

data_duplicate <- data_table[sequence %in% data_table[duplicated(data_table$sequence),]$sequence]
```

However, my problem is that I've got some sequences duplicated but with different modifications. For example in the example:

```
DAT | atggggg  | NULL        | ... | project 
DAT | atggggg  | 7.UN        | ... | project
```

Is there any way to use two conditions in duplicate function using the column "sequence" and the column "modification"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `new_data_frame_PEP` is a data frame and you want to retrieve the rows that have duplicates in `sequence`, you can **instead** use:

```
res <- new_data_frame_PEP[duplicated(new_data_frame_PEP$sequence) |
                          duplicated(new_data_frame_PEP$sequence, fromLast=TRUE),]
```

Here, we call `duplicated` twice: first from the start of the `sequence` column to the end and then from the end back to the start using `fromLast`. `duplicated` returns a logical which is or'ed (i.e., `|`) so that we retrieve all the row indices that have duplicates. We then subset rows of `new_data_frame_PEP` with respect to those.

To accomplish the same with more than one column so that we find all rows that have duplicated values in both the `sequence` and `modification` columns, we need to select those columns to pass to `duplicated`. This can be done using `subset`:

```
seq.mod <- subset(new_data_frame_PEP, select=c("sequence","modification"))
data_duplicate <- new_data_frame_PEP[duplicated(seq.mod) | duplicated(seq.mod, fromLast=TRUE),]
```

To illustrate, we create a data set that is what you posted except we only include the `ID`, `sequence`, `modification`, and `n_project` columns. In addition, we duplicate the first row so that we actually have duplicates in both `sequence` and `modification`:

```
new_data_frame_PEP <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "DAT ", class = "factor"), sequence = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c(" actgat   ", 
" atagattg ", " atatagag ", " atggggg  ", " atgtagtt ", " gggatgac ", 
" tatatccc ", " ttttaaat "), class = "factor"), modification = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c(" 7.UN  ", " 8.UN  ", 
" 9.AT  ", " NULL  "), class = "factor"), n_project = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = " project ", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"sequence", "modification", "n_project"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
##    ID   sequence modification n_project
##1  DAT   atggggg         NULL    project 
##2  DAT   atggggg         NULL    project 
##3  DAT   atggggg         7.UN    project 
##4  DAT   actgat          NULL    project 
##5  DAT   atgtagtt        NULL    project 
##6  DAT   ttttaaat        8.UN    project 
##7  DAT   tatatccc        NULL    project 
##8  DAT   atagattg        9.AT    project 
##9  DAT   atatagag        NULL    project 
##10 DAT   gggatgac        NULL    project
```

Using only `sequence`, we get:

```
seq.only <- subset(new_data_frame_PEP, select=c("sequence"))
data_duplicate <- new_data_frame_PEP[duplicated(seq.only) | duplicated(seq.only, fromLast=TRUE),]
##   ID   sequence modification n_project
##1 DAT   atggggg         NULL    project 
##2 DAT   atggggg         NULL    project 
##3 DAT   atggggg         7.UN    project
```

Using both `sequence` and `modification`:

```
seq.mod <- subset(new_data_frame_PEP, select=c("sequence","modification"))
data_duplicate <- new_data_frame_PEP[duplicated(seq.mod) | duplicated(seq.mod, fromLast=TRUE),]
##   ID   sequence modification n_project
##1 DAT   atggggg         NULL    project 
##2 DAT   atggggg         NULL    project
```